# find duplicate records in related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, having

Consider the following data structure:

```
parking garages
    |
    |_ garage 1
        |__ red car
        |__ blue car
    |_ garage 2
        |__ yellow car
        |__ orange car
    |_ garage 3
        |__ red car
        |__ red car
        |__ yellow car
```

"parking garages" is a table, and each entry is a foreign key to a "garageCars" table containing one record for each car in the garage.

What I would like to do is write a query that would return "garage 3" because it has 2 red cars

I've tried using the HAVING clause with a count, but this returns all the rows that have more than 1 car. I need something more along the lines of "WHERE count(car) > 1 and car.color = car.color".

Comment: select car, count(*) from Garage group by car will give you count of cars in a garage. what is your table structure? two tables Garage and Car?

Comment: yes it is two tables. car and garage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only want the garage name and  not the color that's duped because you want "... query that would return "garage 3" because it has 2 red cars"

Using a Derived Table

```
SELECT g.garagename 
FROM   garage g 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT garage_id 
                   FROM   cars 
                   GROUP  BY garage_id, 
                             carcolor 
                   HAVING COUNT(garage_id) > 1) c 
         ON g.garage_id = c.garage_id
```

Using IN

```
SELECT g.garagename 
FROM   garage g 
WHERE  g.garage_id IN (SELECT garage_id 
                       FROM   cars 
                       GROUP  BY garage_id, 
                                 carcolor 
                       HAVING COUNT(garage_id) > 1)
```

You could also do it with EXISTS, CROSS APPLY or with a CTE

Comment: the IN version worked like a charm! I did not try the derived table version, as the IN version did the trick. THANK YOU!